# Geth Private Network Problems

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, geth-debugging, geth-clique

I am trying to set up a geth private network on my windows laptop and am failing badly at it as i cannot understand anything that's happening. The documentation on geth website is horrible and I just am very sad.

Can anyone help, please? Does anyone have a cheatsheet?

Thanks for any help.